# SwiftUI Generics

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

How can I combine these two views into one `PickerFromOptions` view that can take either an `enum` options or a `[String] option parameter?

I realize I can just leave these as two separate views and call the correct one depending on what I want to pass it, however, I'm trying to understand Generics better and so I'd like to see how I can make just one view that handles both scenarios. So far I've had troubles combining these into one view.

I also realize I could map the enum to a string array to pass, but then storing the selection back into the data model would have to go through more "hoops".

```
struct PickerFromEnumOptions<SelectionType, OptionType>: View where SelectionType: Hashable, OptionType: Identifiable & RawRepresentable & Hashable   {
    var label: String
    var options: [OptionType]
    @Binding var selection: SelectionType
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(label, selection:$selection) {
            ForEach(options) { option in
                Text("\(option.rawValue as! String)")
                    .tag(option)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PickerFromStringArrayOptions<SelectionType, OptionType>: View where SelectionType: Hashable, OptionType: StringProtocol {
    var label: String
    var options: [OptionType]
    @Binding var selection: SelectionType
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(label, selection:$selection) {
            ForEach(options, id:\.self) { option in
                Text("\(option as! String)")
                    .tag(option)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call it using an Enum for the options like this:

```
    
    enum enumOptions: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case one, two, three
        
        var id: String { self.rawValue }
    }

@State var enumSelection: enumOptions
    PickerFromOptions(label: "enumOptions", options: enumOptions.allCases, selection: $enumOptionSelection)
```

or from an array of string options like this:

```
let stringOptions = ["one", "two", "three"]
    
    @State var stringSelection: String
    PickerFromOptions(label: "stringOptions", options: stringOptions, selection: $stringSelection)
```

My first thought was to make OptionType just conform to Hashable, but then it seemed like I have to do runtime type checking to determine how to get the id and string value.

Comment: The usual strategy for something like this is to have one canonical representation, and every API just adapts to it in one form for another. So for example, you might want your underlying storage to always be an `Array<Option>`. That would obviously accommodate the array-based API directly, but it can also work with an enum-based API, which takes a `CaseIterable` enum, and calls `allValues` on it to get an array of cases out. That can then be what you store in your array.

Comment: Side note: Don't do stuff like `Text("\(option.rawValue as! String)")`, there's a bunch wrong with it. The `rawValue` might not be string (because you have a `OptionType: RawRepresentable` constraint but not `OptionType.RawValue == String`), so that `as!` can just flat out crash. Also, when you do `as! String`, you already have a string, there's no need to wrap it in a `"\()"` (which is a sketchy way to convert to a string, in any case). With the correct constraints, you just need `Text(option.rawValue)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I prefer to do some changes first to what to use generics for, first of all I think it's better to have a generic type for the actual collection rather than the element of the collection.

The requirement for using `ForEach` is that the collection conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` so the generic type will then be

```
<OptionsType: RandomAccessCollection>
```

And since we now use a collection we don't need the second generic type since this will be `RandomAccessCollection.Element`.

```
struct PickerFromOptions<OptionsType: RandomAccessCollection>: View
```

We want the `Element` type to conform to `Hashable` and here I also make it conform to `CustomStringConvertible` so we have something to display in the `Picker`

```
where OptionsType.Element: Hashable, OptionsType.Element: CustomStringConvertible
```

I also prefer to let the selection property to be optional so we can start with nothing selected.

So the generic view then becomes

```
struct PickerFromOptions<OptionsType: RandomAccessCollection>: View where OptionsType.Element: Hashable,
                                                                            OptionsType.Element: CustomStringConvertible  {
    var label: String
    var options: OptionsType
    @Binding var selection: OptionsType.Element?

    var body: some View {
        Picker(label, selection:$selection) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Text(option.description)
                    .tag(Optional(option))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A usage example

```
@State var enumSelection: enumOptions?
@State var stringSelection: String?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        PickerFromOptions(label: "enumOptions", options: enumOptions.allCases, selection: $enumSelection)
        PickerFromOptions(label: "stringOptions", options: stringOptions, selection: $stringSelection)
    }
    .padding()
}
```

If you don't want to use `CustomStringConvertible` an alternative and perhaps better solution is to introduce a protocol that the elements need to conform to

```
protocol OptionsElement: Hashable {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

And then we slightly change the implementation

```
struct PickerFromOptionsCustom<OptionsType: RandomAccessCollection>: View where OptionsType.Element: OptionsElement  {
    var label: String
    var options: OptionsType
    @Binding var selection: OptionsType.Element?

    var body: some View {
        Picker(label, selection:$selection) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Text(option.name)
                    .tag(option)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even add an initiailizer (in an `extension`, so as to not replace the preexisting compiler-generated memberwise initializer) which takes an enum type, does a `self.init(label: label, options: EnumType.self.allCases, selection: $selection)`.

Answer (score 0):

When the `Enum` and `String`s are the same, I would go with an `Enum` like so:

```
enum Numbers: String, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
@State var selection: Numbers

Picker("Picker", selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(Numbers.allCases, id: \.self) { number in
        Text(number.rawValue)
    }
}
```

This gives you the safety of not missing a character and an overview of all possible options.

Comment: Enums are my preferred way to do it, however, there's use cases where users can enter their own options to be used in pickers, so that's why the need for [String] as an option